# Django select_related not returning foreign table data

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My Models are related as below (`Milestone` and `Ticket`)

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
  create_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  milestone = models.ForeignKey(Milestone)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  priority = models.IntegerField()
  estimate = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Milestone(models.Model):
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  description = models.TextField()
  budget = models.IntegerField()
```

and I want to get all data from `Ticket` model as well as corresponding `Milestone` table data (JOIN Between Ticket & Milestone)
My query is

```
Ticket.objects.filter(project_id=10).select_related('milestone').values_list()
```

But this is only getting all data from `Ticket` model. Why `Milestone` model's data are not returning? What is wrong here? Please help I am new in Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `select_related` you are caching `Milestone` object asociated to the current `Ticket` object, not retrieving its data.

You could try:

```
from django.db.models import F

tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(project_id=10).select_related('milestone').annotate(m_title=F('milestone__title'), m_description=F('milestone__description'), ...)
```

Then, the objects in the resulting queryset will have a `m_title` attribute.

```
tickets[0].m_title
```

Comment: how can i get list data? for both tables. Will it return both tables all data

Comment: Well, you have a QuerySet object in tickets. You can add `.values_list()` at the end and get a list with the annotated values included.

Comment: its working in shell. please wait testing in project

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks a ton. Last quick question how can I do this for  `TestModel` which is override `AbstractBaseUser` Class rather than model. Is it possible

Comment: If you mean `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model, yes, you can It's a model like any other.

Comment: well can i use more than 2 table data here i.e `Ticket`, `MileStone` and `ThirdModel`...?? how will be the `select_related()` then? `select_related('milestone').select_related('third')` like this?

Comment: It depends the relationship, you can follow relationship with underscore notation '`__`'. So if `third` belogs to `milestone` it would be `milestone__third`, but if `third` belongs to `ticket` it is just `third`.

Comment: Problem solved, your all solution worked. Thanks you boss :)